# Segmentation fault:11 in my code for creating a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm very new to programming, so I would like you to keep in mind theres a high chance I've made a very dumb or basic mistake. I have run into this problem while trying to create a linked list in C. For the output, I'm able to enter 2 elements before I get a segmentation fault:11.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void create(){
    int temp1,temp2;
    printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp1);
    struct node *x=(struct node*)malloc(temp1*sizeof(struct node*));
    for(int i=0;i<temp1;i++){
        printf("loop\n");
        printf("Enter a value\n");
        scanf("%d",&temp2);
        x->data=temp2;
        printf("text\n");

        x=x->next;
    }
x->next=NULL;
}
int main(){
    create();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is not designed to debug code for you, and as such, this question is off-topic. Check out [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think that this, while a experienced programmer may find this in a debugger, is less a debugging question than a newbie question. Which makes it valid. At least he gave an MVCE and a problem description.

Answer (score 2):

```
        x=x->next;
    }
x->next=NULL;
```

you  have not allocated any memory for the next and then you dereference it.

BTW you do not save anywhere the fist node so after the function call the list and allocated memory is lost

Comment: Also `sizeof(struct node*)` is wrong -- it should be `sizeof(struct node)`. Right now he's just allocating space for a *pointer*.

Comment: A lots of issues :)

Answer (score -2):

Hi I modified your code a bit. Below is the modified version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void print(struct node *head) {
    while(head){
        printf("%d->", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void free_mem(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp;
    while(head){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
//Insertion at the end
struct node *create(struct node *head){
    int temp1,temp2;
    struct node *temp_node;
    printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&temp1) < 1){
        printf("scanf for temp1 failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<temp1;i++){
        struct node *x;
        if(! (x = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))){
            printf("malloc of new node failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter a value\n");
        if(scanf("%d",&temp2) < 1){
            printf("scanf for temp2 failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        x->data=temp2;
        x->next = NULL;
        if(!head){
            head = x;
            head->next = NULL;
            continue;
        }
        //Moving to end
        temp_node = head;
        while(temp_node->next){
            temp_node = temp_node->next;
        }
        temp_node->next = x;
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    head = create(head);
    print(head);
    //freeing dynamically allocated memory
    free_mem(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Please revert for any clarifications.

Comment: After create the list is lost and memory leaked.

Comment: very bad code as for an answer and example - no malloc & scanf checks and many other issues